# How to merge these parent/child javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with two json API endpoints, one that returns 'posts' and the other 'comments' associated with the posts.  Examples:

```
/*posts*/
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }
]

/*comments*/
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  }
]
```

My end result should be (using the first post as a template):

```
[
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":1,
      "title":"sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body":"quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
      "comments":[
         {
            "postId":1,
            "id":1,
            "name":"id labore ex et quam laborum",
            "email":"Eliseo@gardner.biz",
            "body":"laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
         },
         {
            "postId":1,
            "id":2,
            "name":"quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
            "email":"Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
            "body":"est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
         },
         {
            "postId":1,
            "id":3,
            "name":"odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
            "email":"Nikita@garfield.biz",
            "body":"quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What's a good way of doing this?  I've never had to merge objects like this before.

Comment: Array methods like map, reduce, forEach etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ES6

```
const result = postsList.map(post => {
    const comments = commentsList.filter(({ postId }) => postId === post.id);

    return { ...post, comments };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a best Solutions but it will work

```
var newArr = []
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < comments.length; j++) {
    if(data[i].id === comments[j].id) {
      data[i].comments = comments[j]
      newArr.push(data[i])
    }
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```